# Interpreting BATS model information using forecast package in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, bats

I have a forecast object in R. When I look at the summary I can see 'Model Information: BATS(1, {1,1}, -, -)'

What do these numbers in the parentheses stand for?

Comment: Can you paste in the complete output & the code to produce it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is the $\omega$ parameter of the Box-Cox transform, the second and third are the ARMA order of the innovation, the rest are the $m_i$ seasonal periods, which in your case are none. I don't want to clutter this post with six equations, but you can find them on p.9-10 of [1]

Ref :

[1] De Livera, A. M., Hyndman, R. J., & Snyder, R. D. (2011). Forecasting time series with complex seasonal patterns using exponential smoothing. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 106(496), 1513-1527. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.450.8320&rep=rep1&type=pdf